# Dual Active Bridge Converters - ZVS

Tags: transistors, dc-dc-converter

I am studying DAB topology which is summarized in a [Texas Instrument paper](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidues0b/tidues0b.pdf)

At page 14, at the Zero Voltage Switching I read about this explanation:

*During the transition from interval one to two, there exists a small dead time where the inductor-stored energy discharges the output capacitances of the MOSFETs and holds them close to zero voltage before they are turned on.*

...and I am little lost. Can someone give me an intuitive explanation of why does the output capacitance of the MOSFETs discharges?

- Because the MOSFET have output capacitance and it behaves like a
  capacitor in order to have full Vds I need to have a current.
- It says that there is a dead time, meaning that the circuit through the inductor is interrupted. When there is no current going through the inductor the magnetic
  field collapses which results in a back EMF, right?
- So, what happens exactly on that inductor that discharges the
  capacitance on Vds making a relative zero voltage on Vds?
- It's the same analogy when you discharge the gate? But in gate analogy
  the current goes to the ground...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the dead-time, the inductance is not clamped to a rail.  The current is not "interrupted".

If the inductor is carrying current at this time (it is) then that current has to continue to flow.  The only place it can flow is into the capacitance (device and stray) of the bridge node it is connected to.

Depending on the direction and magnitude of the current, that will either slew the voltage below ground until it turns on the FET body diode (as in this case) or above the rail until clamped by the upper body diode. (Or just ring with the capacitance if there's not enough energy to get to one of the rails.)

So under the right conditions the current in the inductor slews the center node of the bridge to ground and after the dead-time the switch turns on with only a diode drop across it. (Essentially ZVS).